# Linux username@server disappears after login as root

Tags: linux, login, users

On my linux server I signed in as the root user to access some files: **su root**...  After checking the files I went to sign back in as my main user **su username**.  In my terminal window it now says **server ~:** instead of **username@server ~:** to the left of the command line.  Is there any way I can get this back to normal?

Answer (score 12):

Do a few `exit` commands.  Your `su root` started a subshell where you're root, and your `su user` started another.  Typing `exit` will end those subshells and bring you back where you started -- one level deep.

Comment: It just exited me out of my remote connection... but I do think that I'm in a subshell.  Is there any command for me to view all the subshells I have running?

Comment: With "echo $SHLVL" you can see the subshell level.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to change the prompt. You can use the following command:

```
export PS1="\u@\h \w: "
```

I personally prefer the following as my prompt, but that's just me:

```
export PS1="[\u@\h \w]\$ "
```

You can prevent your prompt from changing by adding the statement to the relevant bashrc files. See also [Bash Shell PS1: 10 Examples to Make Your Linux Prompt like Angelina Jolie](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/) for more info about PS1.

Comment: Why would changing users change my prompt?  This seems like more of a workaround than a fix.

Comment: Because the prompt will indicate as WHAT user you're currently operating, e.g. the prompt would look like root@myserver: when you're operating as the root user or someuser@myserver: when you're operating under the credentials of someuser.

Comment: David: Prompts are not global; They are user-specific. Therefore, changing users can change your prompt. In particular, the root user oftentimes has a very bare-bones generic prompt. What Michael suggested here is exactly the correct way to address your problem; It's not at all a workaround.

Comment: Since they are user-specific, why would changing to the root user change the prompt for the user "david."  I understand that when I am in the sub-shell for the root user that I would have a different prompt, but as soon as I exit out of that subshell I don't understand why it would change the prompt for the user david.  Didn't you just say that they are independent of each other?  I'm definitely a noob at linux, and I would appreciate it if someone could explain the error in my logic here.

Comment: While this answer is correct about how to change bash prompts, it misses the point that to "switch back" to your own user after a `su`, you typically simply want to `exit` the `su`-shell, not start another one.

Comment: 1) Prompt is governed by ENV variables (as above). 2) `su` starts a subshell and erases its parent ENV variables. 3) the child subshell inherits ENV varibles from the initialisation script for the user the shell as running as ( david ).

Answer (score 5):

`su` switches users by spawning a new (sub)shell. So when you logged in, you started a shell. With the first `su` to root, you started a subshell as root. The next `su` to your user started yet another subshell -- note that at this moment you have three shells running. So instead of `su`-ing to your user from the rootshell, `exit`-ing back to your login shell will solve your problems.

If you have `pstree` installed, `pstree -h` will show you a graphical representation of what's going on.

Comment: That reads: -sshd---sshd---sshd---bash---pstree.   When I enter the root sub-shell I get: -sshd---sshd---sshd---bash---su---bash---pstree.  Since there is only one bash in the first reading would I be correct in assuming that I'm not in a sub-shell?

Comment: Exactly. So to get out of any unnecessary subshell, just `exit` until there's only one `bash` left.

Answer (score 4):

Your prompt appears to be normally set by one of your shell startup files that is *not* being run when you `su` from root to your user. If you're using bash, `man bash` in the INVOCATION section might be enlightening. There are several startup files that bash might read, including but not limited to:

- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`

The `PS1` environment variable is just an environment variable, and may or may not get set depending on which combination of the above files is run.

The `su` command has a `-l` (or `--login`) switch which may be abbreviated to just `-` that makes the new shell a login shell. This is probably what you want:

```
su - david
```

I always use `su` with this option.

Comment: That's correct. A plain su would not invoke the startup files whereas su - would.
I didn't know su - is short for su -l ! Thanks Greg for the info.

Comment: also, for 'sudo' people, "sudo -i" is *immensely* handy

Answer (score 1):

if this is a bash shell, try:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

if that doesnt work run `echo $PS1` and see what has changed.

Comment: . ~/.bashrc does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

`su` by itself does not create a new session of the shell. that's why it doesn't set up the shell as it normally does. however,

```
su -
```

will start a new login session